# Why init.. methods are required in Objective C?

Tags: ios, objective-c

Wherever I've read, it's written to never use an object without calling it's initializer function. And initializer functions always "have to" start with "init".

Is there a reason behind this naming (Does naming a method starting with init do something special)? What happens if I do not call the initializer function i.e. if I just do **[MyClass alloc]** and start using the object?

Comment: In past what programming language you work?

Comment: Do you know of an O-O language that *does not* use init methods?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading the Apple Documentation on [Object Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/CocoaEncyclopedia/Initialization/Initialization.html), and [Initialization](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Initialization.html).

> Is there a reason behind this naming (Does naming a method starting with init do something special)?

It is the convention, beginning a method name with init does not do anything special.

There are some minor quirks, such as if a method beginning with init returns type `id`, the compiler will convert the return type to `instancetype`, but these are barely worth mentioning.

> What happens if I do not call the initializer function i.e. if I just do [MyClass alloc] and start using the object?

If you're using a standard SDK class, you'll likely run into a crash / exception. Initialization is used to set up the initial state of the instance variables, and without doing this can lead to undefined behaviour.

For a small example, if you called `[[MyObject alloc] vegetable];` with the following class, you'd get nil returned because _vegetable hasn't been assigned.

```
@interface MyObject : NSObject

-(NSString*)vegetable;

@end

@implementation MyObject {
    NSString *_vegetable;
}

-(instancetype)init {
    self = [super init];
    if (self) {
        _vegetable = @"Cabbage";
    }
    return self;
}

-(NSString*)vegetable {
    return _vegetable;
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

`Alloc` is called to allocate space in memory for the data type you are specifying. Whether it is `NSString` or `NSNumber`, calling `Alloc` will reserve the most efficient space in memory as possible for that data type (small or large).

`Init` is called to instantiate the class and superclass's important variables. These variables could include the `Rect` to recalculate a certain size in order to layout subviews, or perhaps instantiate with a `delegate` of some kind to perform some protocol upon creation. If it all becomes too much for you Objective-C does allow you to instantiate objects like `MyClass *myObject = [MyClass new];`

It may all seem redundant and a waste of time, but fortunately **Swift** has cut down tremendous amounts of redundancies like this in the new programming language. Now all you have to do is `var myObject = MyClass()` and if there are any custom initializers they would likely be writen like so `var myObject = MyClass(frame: CGRectZero)`

Happy coding!

Answer (score -1):

It is the way you create objects in Objective-C. It is a hard requirement of the language. Creating an object in Objective-C is a 2 step process: alloc and init.

Under the covers, the reason you must call init is, wait for it, initialization.

The call to alloc creates a block of memory for your object and zeros it out. Calling init allows the object and it's ancestors to set things up so the object is ready to function. It initializes the object's memory and does other housekeeping that set the object up.

Further, every object's init method needs to call super init, so the initialization goes all the way up the object chain, all the way to NSObject. All the ancestor classes are designed to assume that their init method is called.

Comment: Can I subclass NSProxy and do initialization inside of alloc?